# What is the parent of an ObjectIdentity?

Tags: symfony, acl

I'm trying to understand how the ACLs works internally. The database schema generated includes a `parent_object_identity_id` column to the `acl_object_identities` table I could not find any information about the parent of an `ObjectIdentity`, it's not even in the definition of the interface. What is it ?

In the same way, what is the ancestor of an `ObjectIdentity` ? I would think that it's the same thing that the parent of an ObjectIdentity, but I don't know what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `parent_object_entity_id` is set, this will point to a parent object identity id found in this same table. When no parent object identity is used, this column will be set to `NULL`.

It's to "chain" entity id's together and it allows you to create more efficient ACLs (instead of creating many ACEs, they can all use the same parent instead).

Think of a forum with topics and blogposts. A moderator could only moderate blogposts in a certain topic, but not others. Normally, this would mean you would add to EACH blogpost in a topic an ACE for the owner, PLUS an ACE for the moderator.

If we have multiple moderators, this could lead into a lot of ACEs for each single blogpost. Instead, we create a moderator ACE on the topic-entity, and "chain" all the blogpost blogpost ACLs to the given topic ACL. This saves a lot of duplication and maintenance on the ACLS. Especially when new moderators are added (you would only need to update one topic ACL, instead of ALL blogpost ACLs etc).

Comment: I don't get the utility of chaining ACEs, what do you mean my chaining ? Creating an ordered array of ACEs ?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your question

Comment: But isn't the parent field in the ObjectIdentity ? Are we talking about ACLs, ACEs, ObjectIdentity, or am I really missing something ? Looking at my MySQL database, the `parent_object_entity_id` field is on the the `acl_object_identities` table

Comment: Things are stored a bit differently on disk as you will use it within symfony (this is purely for speed reasons). So when the ACL checks all the aces for the given object identity, and cannot find them, it will check the ACES for the given parent_object_entity_id, and the next etc until no parents are left.. (it's actually a bit worse, as there is also something called class-scoped ACE, but i would not recommend that system).